# Loop em javascript com intervalos

Tags: javascript, angular

Preciso fazer um loop onde a cada iteração ele espere 2 segundos até a proxima. Eu tentei com setInterval, mas vi que ele não funciona como quero... Pois é assincorno, então o loop roda normal, só chamando o set interval que roda no tempo dele... como faço para que haja um delay em cada iteração?

função que fiz e não funciona como preciso:

```
while ((!this.service.levelsLoaded)) {
      setInterval(function() { }, 2000);
}
```

Comment: O que exatamente você precisa que seja feito? O trecho de código que você colocou é muito pequeno e não ajuda com a resposta... Tente **[edit]** a sua pergunta para colocar mais detalhes.

Comment: ops eu coloquei if em vez de while... e preciso que a cada iteração do while ele dê tipo um sleep... do jeito que está, ele espera 2 segundos e depois dispara tudo

Answer (score 1):

O melhor seria atribuir o valor de retorno de `setInterval` á uma variável, executar o que você deseja a cada 2 segundos dentro do callback de `setInterval` e, quando quiser finalizar, chamar `clearInterval` fornecendo o retorno de `setInterval` como argumento. Mas, tem um jeito de manter o seu loop usando `async`, `await` e `Promise`:

```js
async function doSomething() {
  while ((!this.service.levelsLoaded)) {
    await new Promise(resolve => {
      // Faça alguma coisa...
      setTimeout(resolve, 2000)
    })
  }
}
```

Ou, se preferir criar uma função para reutilização:

```js
async function sleep(time) {
  await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, time))
}

async function doSomething() {
  while ((!this.service.levelsLoaded)) {
    // Faça alguma coisa
    await sleep(2000)
  }
}
```